# Why is $I^j I^k\subseteq I^{j+k}$ if $I$ is an ideal of a commutative ring $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $I$ be an ideal of a commutative ring $R$. P. Aluffi says that for all $j,k$ we have that
$$I^j I^k\subseteq I^{j+k}.$$
Since $I^k$ is defined as being $I\cdot I\cdot\dotsc\cdot I$ ($k$ times), I don't see why we wouldn't have equality. What am I missing here?

Also, anything changes if $R$ is not commutative?

Comment: You do have equality. I suspect Aluffi was just trying to say that only the $\subseteq$ part will be used.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thats perfect. If you'd like, you can write that as an answer and I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't missing anything. It is true that $I^j I^k = I^{j+k}$ (and it follows immediately from the fact that [the ideals of $R$ form a monoid with respect to multiplication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302534/generator-of-power-of-ideal/3302558#3302558)). The reason why Aluffi was only writing the $\subseteq$ sign is probably that he was only needing the $\subseteq$ sign and thus avoiding a little mental detour. (If you give me the exact location of the statement, I can comment with greater certainty.)

And yes, this all remains true when $R$ is noncommutative. Indeed, if $U$ and $V$ are two ideals of $R$, then the $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $R$ spanned by all products of the form $uv$ with $u \in U$ and $v \in V$ is again an ideal of $R$, and therefore the product operation is well-defined; its associativity can be easily seen as a consequence of the associativity of multiplication of $R$.

Furthermore, this all remains true when $R$ is nonunital, as long as $j$ and $k$ are positive. (We could still define $I^0$ to be $R$, but it would not be a very useful thing to do, since $R$ is no longer the neutral element of the semigroup of ideals of $R$ when $R$ is nonunital.)

Comment: That was exactly it. It says that before asking us to define the Rees algebra of an ideal. I guess he wanted us to see how it relates to the multiplication of polynomials.

Comment: @Gabriel: Ah, I see. You can indeed define the Rees algebra for any ideal semifiltration (see, e.g., Definitions 2.1 and 2.7 in [arXiv:1907.06125v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.06125v1)), and those only need the $\subseteq$ sign.